# Getting the outer div in JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get selected element's outer HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/get-selected-elements-outer-html)

I'm getting a class like this:

```
   <div class="className">
      content in here
   </div>
```

And then I'm getting it in JQuery like this:

```
$('.className').html()
```

Which only outputs:

```
content in here
```

When I want it to get everything, including the parent div.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Do you mean including the current div tags? or Parent div content(which will have other content along with the current div and its content)?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/get-selected-elements-outer-html (duplicate)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.className').clone().wrap('<div></div>').parent().html();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ipr101/WX69N/